# How to diagnose this error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I'm trying to run [voxel-hello-world](https://github.com/maxogden/voxel-hello-world) (a Minecraft-like game, which runs in the browser). I get the following error when I try to access the page at localhost:

```
4 verbose stack Error: voxel-hello-world@0.6.0 start: `beefy test.js:bundle.js 8080`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:242:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
```

Details (incl. npm-debug.log) can be found [here](http://altruix.cc/caw/attempt-to-run-voxel-hello-world/).

I have no experience with Node.js. My suspicion was that the version of Node.js may be compatible with this code, which AFAIK was written couple of years ago. I tried several older versions of Node.js with the same result.

How can I fix this error? What is it root cause?

**Update 1:** When I run `beefy test.js:bundle.js`, I get this:

```
C:\dev\voxel-hello-world>beefy test.js:bundle.js 8080
module.js:457
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world\node_modules\browserify/bin/args.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at setupBrowserify (C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\beefy\lib\bundlers\browserify.js:6:19)
    at onlocalbrowserify (C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\beefy\lib\setup-bundlers.js:30:5)
    at C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\beefy\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:42:21
    at C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\beefy\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:121:35
    at C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\beefy\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:93:39
    at C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\beefy\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:59:30
```

I tried to install browserify...

```
C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world>npm install browserify -g
C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\browserify -> C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\bin\cmd.js
C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- browserify@13.1.0
```

But then the same error came.

**Update 2:** Changing the port to 8085 doesn't help.

```
C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world>npm start

> voxel-hello-world@0.6.0 start C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world
> beefy test.js:bundle.js 8085

listening on 8085
using .\node_modules\.bin\browserify
200   75ms    1.08KB /index.html
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world\node_modules\.bin\browserify ENOENT
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32)
  at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)


npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! voxel-hello-world@0.6.0 start: `beefy test.js:bundle.js 8085`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the voxel-hello-world@0.6.0 start script 'beefy test.js:bundle.js 8085'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the voxel-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     beefy test.js:bundle.js 8085
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs voxel-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls voxel-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world>
```

**Update 3:** Running

```
npm install beefy
npm install browserify
```

doesn't help.

**Update 4:** Here's the contens of the directory `voxel-hello-world\node_modules\.bin\`.

[image: Screenshot]

**Update 5:** According to the output of `npm --verbose start` npm tries to execute the command `beefy test.js:bundle.js 8085`:

```
C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world>npm --verbose start
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   'start' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.3
npm info using node@v6.4.0
npm verb run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
npm info lifecycle voxel-hello-world@0.6.0~prestart: voxel-hello-world@0.6.0
npm info lifecycle voxel-hello-world@0.6.0~start: voxel-hello-world@0.6.0
```

> voxel-hello-world@0.6.0 start C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world
>   beefy test.js:bundle.js 8085

When I try to run that command myself, it can't find file `C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world\node_modules\browserify/bin/args.js`, which doesn't exist in that directory (see screenshot below).

```
C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world>beefy test.js:bundle.js 8085
module.js:457
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world\node_modules\browserify/bin/args.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at setupBrowserify (C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\beefy\lib\bundlers\browserify.js:6:19)
    at onlocalbrowserify (C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\beefy\lib\setup-bundlers.js:30:5)
    at C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\beefy\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:42:21
    at C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\beefy\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:121:35
    at C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\beefy\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:93:39
    at C:\Users\pisarenko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\beefy\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:59:30
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: There are some issues in the repo that seem related. Maybe [this one](https://github.com/maxogden/voxel-hello-world/issues/26) might help?

Comment: I tried, what they recommend. It doesn't help (see update 3). Is there a way to run `npm start` with verbose output? Or - how can I find out, in what package the problematic (`events.js:160`) code is located?

Comment: `npm --verbose start` should do it.

Comment: Thanks. It fails because it tries to find file `C:\Users\pisarenko\Documents\dev\voxel-hello-world\node_modules\browserify/bin/args.js` and there is no `args.js` in the specified directory. See update 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick workaround: edit `voxel-hello-world/node_modules/beefy/index.js`, replace this line (line 64?):

`bfy = spawn(browserify_path, args)`

with

`bfy = spawn(browserify_path, args, {shell: true})`

, then `npm start`, open it in chrome

[image: Screenshot]

I reproduced same error with following commands in git bash:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/maxogden/voxel-hello-world
$ cd voxel-hello-world/
$ npm -v
3.3.6
$ node -v
v6.1.0
$ cmd /c ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
> exit
$ npm i
$ npm start
```

[`beefy`](https://github.com/chrisdickinson/beefy) [spawns](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) command line `browserify` without shell, this works on Linux since `node_modules/.bin/browserify` is a valid executable. But Windows can't execute it.

Adding the options `{shell: true}` is to start a shell (`cmd.exe`) and run the command in it, `browserify` resolves to the batch file `browserify.cmd` in the shell.

Global installation of `browserify` or other packages are not required, `npm start` and other `npm` scripts automatically adds executable of local packages to `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll award the bounty in approx. 2 hours (StackOverflow rules).